# Sending PHP emails with HTML/CSS

Tags: php, css, email

I'm trying to send emails with PHP. I would like to add some style with CSS (no matter if inline, internal or with external file).

I've tried [**PHPmailer**](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), but it fails to recognize some elements (such as `body`), media queries (`@media`) and declarations (`max-width`, `inline-block`, etc...). I'm now trying to use [**SwiftMailer**](http://swiftmailer.org/), but online documentation doesn't mention anything about styling.

Just for sake of clarity, here's the snippet I would like to use: **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg5Ev/)**

Any ideas to send PHP emails with working HTML/CSS?

Comment: you have to add inline CSS to customize html elements in mail

Comment: you have to use inline css for your design and use mail() function.

Comment: You can look here for allowed CSS within email clients: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ There is a reason why there is a whole business model around email campaigns and there is a lot of knowledge to obtain if you want to do it 100% correct.

Comment: I think this question is too broad. But since html mails can be a real pain, it's worth having a look here: http://zurb.com/ink/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CSS inliner tool like http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/
to convert your 'normal' template (made like a normal HTML page) to an email-friendly template. This is needed because mail clients doesn't recognise separate  elements.
I currently use a template based on the ones made available by Zurb, http://zurb.com/ink/

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the receiver's email client. Not all clients accept all css. Use a litmus test of some sort to check with different e-mail clients which css you can use. Tables often work with email clients, a lot of them don't accept divs I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I use **PHPMailer** to send emails with PHP, and it never fails to recognize these elements (for me anyway).

To use it, i create a fonction :

```
function sendMail($name, $from, $message, $to, $subject)
{
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $body = "<html><head></head><body style=\"background-color: #F2F1F0;\"><p>".$message."</p></body></html>";
   $mail->SetFrom($from, $name);    
   $mail->AddReplyTo($from, $name);

   // Only if you want to send an attachment, send a variable $object to the function
   //$mail->AddAttachment($object);

   $mail->Subject    = $subject;    
   $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test    
   $mail->MsgHTML($body);      
   $mail->AddAddress($to, $name);

   if(!$mail->Send()) {
       $result = $mail->ErrorInfo;
   }
   else
   {
       $result = "Mail sent successfully";
   }
   return $result;
}
```

And an exemple to use it :

```
// Preparation of the message
$message = '<p class="img"><img src="http://mywebsite.com/img/myImage.png" width="220px"></p>';
$message .= '<p class="txt">Hello Mr Dupond !</p>';
$message .= '<p class="txt">We are glad to have you among us</p>';
$message .= '<p class="txt">Se you soon on our Website !</p>';
$message = utf8_decode($message);

// variables needed
$name = "Mr Oktopuss";
$from = "contact@oktopuss.eu";
$to = "contactAddress@domain.ext";
$subject = "The subject of this mail !";

// Send the mail and receive the result
$result = sendMail($name, $from, $message, $to, $subject);
echo $result;
```

Maybe that could be help you